# Getting error while trying to update pod file in my Xcode by using pod clean command?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode10

pod clean giving me the below error any ideas ..?

note: I am using Xcode 10

Ignoring ffi-1.9.25 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.25

Ignoring redcarpet-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet --version 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have to install the missing gems once I done that I am able to to clean and update.